# Shape error for LSTM layer in my image classification model

Tags: python, recurrent-neural-network, conv-neural-network

Hello I am trying to classify grayscale images (224x224) and I am trying to use LSTM for that but I keep getting the shape errors

my train datagenerator looks like this:

```
def train_datagenerator(train_batchsize):
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1 / 255.0,
    rotation_range=20,
    zoom_range=0.05,
    width_shift_range=0.05,
    height_shift_range=0.05,
    shear_range=0.05,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode="nearest")

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                    target_size=(image_size, image_size),
                                                    batch_size=train_batchsize,
                                                    class_mode='categorical')
return train_generator
```

this is my code for my model:

```
def LSTM_model():

 model = Sequential()
 model.add(LSTM(512, input_shape=(224, 224)))
 model.add(Flatten())
 model.add(Dense(1024))
 model.add(Activation('relu'))
 model.add(Dense(50))
 model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
 model.add(Dense(3))  
 model.add(Activation('softmax'))


 model.build()
 model.summary()
 return model
```

model.fit

```
def train(model):
train_generator = train_datagenerator(train_batchsize)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              #optimizer='sgd',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['acc'])
train_start = time.clock()

print('Started training...')
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples / train_generator.batch_size,
                              epochs=epochs,
                              verbose=1)

train_finish = time.clock()
train_time = train_finish - train_start
print('Training completed in {0:.3f} minutes!'.format(train_time / 60))

print('Saving the trained model...')
model.save('/content/drive/My Drive/Project/trained_models/rnn_model.h5')
print("Saved trained model in 'trained_models/ folder'!")

return model, history
```

I get this error: Input 0 of layer lstm_5 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 150528]

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I m not sure but can you try to this

`model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(224, 224)))`

Comment: I tried and now I am getting this error: Input 0 of layer lstm_6 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 224, 224, 1]

Comment: @Raja can you share your model.fit, normally train generator return [batch_size, img_size, img_size, channel_size]. Or can you share more your code?

Comment: I just shared it in my question. you can see it there. and thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Hello. I tried that and I get this error now: ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_27 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, None, None, None]

Comment: @Raja hi Raja, I just check gray image classification with lstm keras, but it's i can't find clear answer, maybe this link [https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7927](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7927) helps you, I am sorry.

Comment: @Raja you can check this link also [https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/58694/2d-input-to-lstm-in-keras](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/58694/2d-input-to-lstm-in-keras)

Comment: You are welcome @Raja, Can you make to my answer is accepted with green teak?

Comment: I jusrt did. Sorry, I am new to this. So, I did not know how this works! Thanks again.